# how to paint Simple graphics when i dragging my mouse on a div like photoshop using Raphael 

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, photoshop, raphael

this is my code :

```
<div id="handle" style="background:#5f3">

</div>
```

and the script is :

```
var set = Raphael(["handle", 400, 400, {
    type: "rect",
    x: 300,
    y: 10,
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    stroke: "blue"
}, {
    type: "text",
    x: 30,
    y: 40,
    text: "Dump"
}]);
```

the demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/ATZNW/

so how to draw Simple graphics (ex: rect ) like photoshop ,

thanks

Comment: Do you want to draw rectangle with mouse? It’s not clear what you mean under “paint Simple graphics when i dragging my mouse”.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael is a Library for [Vector Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Graphics), what you want to do is [Raster Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics).

The HTML `<canvas>` element is exactly what you need in this case.

```
<canvas id="bg" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Some basic JavaScript:

```
var bg = document.getElementById('bg').getContext('2d'); // retrieve the 2d context to draw on
bg.fillStyle = '#ff0000'; // set the fill color to red

// draw a filled rectangle at 20/20 thats 200x100 pixel in size
bg.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 100);
```

For more information on the topic check out [Mozilla's Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial).

Comment: How is Canvas is more suitable for the task?

Comment: @Dmitry Because of "Simple graphics (ex: rect ) like photoshop"? For me it seems that he wants to emulate painting with a brush by moving the mouse(?)

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t get the question either.